# How to to use Docker for ElectronJS app built in Windows?

Tags: node.js, docker, electron

I am working on a desktop application build using ElectronJS framework on Windows.

May be I haven't understood Docker properly, but how do I use docker for this app?

My end goal is to not let people install node, npm and electron packages on their local system. They can use the docker image to develop this application.

**Update**
I figured out how to package my project in docker image. Now I am struggling to run the app through the Docker Container.

**How to run a GUI(Electron Application) application using docker container?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need custom docker images that will have `node`, `npm` and `ElectronJS` in it.

I found one such [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/electronuserland/electron-builder/) on dockerhub, you can use it or build your own custom image by checking its [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/electronuserland/electron-builder/dockerfile).